# unable to resize gke cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a `GKE` cluster with 2 nodes. A web application runs on them. I changed the `.yaml` file to have only one replica of the application.

Now I want to reduce the size of the cluster to 1 but the cluster size seems to stay two.

I have tried several options (editing default pool size via UI and also the following command - `gcloud container clusters resize myclustername --node-pool mypoolname --num-nodes 1`

But after the operation finishes, I still see two nodes.

```
gcloud container clusters resize myclustername --node-pool mypoolname --num-nodes 1
Pool [default-pool] for [...] will be resized to 1.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Resizing codingjedi-web...done.
Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../zones/europe-west2-a/clusters/...].
no_reply@cloudshell:~ (...)$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
gke-...-default-pool-d842095f-nq6t   Ready    <none>   3m48s   v1.16.15-gke.4901
gke-...-default-pool-d842095f-zdlr   Ready    <none>   12m     v1.16.15-gke.4901
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the auto-scaler immediately scaled up after you resized your cluster.
Some research on logs could clarify the events triggered after the cluster resize.

Answer (score 0):

I had to first disable auto scaling on the cluster.

Comment: As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster#decrease_with_drain), "Do not use both Cluster Autoscaler and manual resize commands simultaneously on a node pool, as this can cause interactions that result in unstable and/or incorrect node pool size."